# AEM - How can I run my JavaScript code only in publish mode?

Tags: aem

In AEM, is it possible to run a JavaScript file only in publish mode but not in author mode?

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what kind of JavaScript file are you using? Is it some client-side or server-side JS? You can look at AEM runmodes approach for your requirement - https://helpx.adobe.com/in/experience-manager/6-4/sites/deploying/using/configure-runmodes.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this

If this is a stand alone module, you can have it in a separate clientlibrary and load the client library only in publish conditionally.

```
<sly data-sly-test="wcmmode.disabled" data-sly-use.clientLib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html"
     data-sly-call="${clientlib.css @ categories='foo'}"/>
```

or

If this is like a small subset of code you want to exclude on author, you can add a data attribute that will imply the wcmmode and then guard those functions with a check based on the data attribute

```
<body data-wcm-mode="${wcmmode.toString}">.....</body>
$(document.body).attr('data-wcm-mode') === "DISABLED"){
     //do something
}
```

or

Author mode has lot of CQ/Granite namespaced objects, you can check for their presence to infer if this is author or publish

```
if(typeof typeof Granite === 'undefined' ||  typeof Granite.author === 'undefined'){
     //do something
}
```

None of these actually imply a real publish server but wcmmode of disabled which would suffice for most use cases. If you must absolutely check for publisher and not just wcmmode, consider checking slingsetting for presence of the publish runmode [https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/sling-settings-org-apache-sling-settings.html].